# Something is wrong with my understanding of this D-Flip flop design

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, logic-gates

I am a little rusty with flip-flops.

Consider this diagram:

[image]

This is a [4 channel stereo digital switcher](http://www.electroschematics.com/2140/stereo-switch/). I am trying to understand the flip flop and the OR parts.

Because this is a 4 channel switcher, my feeling says that the flip-flops and the OR gates will be providing 4 different outputs and I am trying to understand how it works.

Lets talk about `FF1` and `FF2`.

When the circuit is first powered, `C15` is an "short circuit" and will let 5 volts reach `R17`, making `FF1` clock be 1 for a brief period of time and then charge and "cut" the current to `R17`, making it 0 volts. So, we see clock going from 1 to 0, during startup.

Because this D-Flip-flop `CD4013` will not do anything on 1 to 0 clock transition, I think `FF1` will be with the following states after startup: (Q = 1), (Q' = 0), (D = 1).

Because of the wiring between `FF1` and `FF2`, after startup `FF2` clock will be 1, (Q = 0), (Q' = 1) and (D = 1).

At this point the `OR` ports will be with these states (from top down):

```
N1 (0, 0).... output 0
N2 (1, 0).... output 1
N3 (0, 1).... output 1
N4 (1, 1).... output 1
```

---

Then I press `S1`. We have a transition from 0 to 1 on FF1 clock.

`FF1` changes to the following states: (Q = 1), (Q' = 0 = D)

Nothing happens on `FF2`.

The `OR` ports are now

```
N1 (1, 0).... output 1
N2 (0, 0).... output 0
N3 (1, 1).... output 1
N4 (1, 0).... output 1
```

---

I press `S1` again. We have a transition from 0 to 1 on `FF1` clock.

`FF1` changes to the following states: (Q = 0), (Q' = 1 = D)

Now the clock of `FF2` changes from 0 to 1

So, `FF2` changes to: (Q = 1), (Q' = 0 = D)

The `OR` ports are now

```
N1 (0, 1).... output 1
N2 (1, 1).... output 1
N3 (0, 0).... output 0
N4 (0, 1).... output 1
```

---

I press `S1` again. We have a transition from 0 to 1 on `FF1` clock.

`FF1` changes to the following states: (Q = 1), (Q' = 0 = D)

Nothing happens on `FF2`.

The `OR` ports are now

```
N1 (1, 1).... output 1
N2 (0, 1).... output 1
N3 (1, 0).... output 1
N4 (0, 0).... output 0
```

---

So, in sequence, the `OR` ports will produce, from top down:

```
0111
1011
1101
1110
```

But here is the problem, `4066` is a switch. Looking at my numbers I see a zero changing position. But in that case, I would expect the inverse of that, I mean

```
1000
0100
0010
0001
```

or a 1 changing position, so this 1 could select one of the four channels of `IC3` and `IC4` as stated by the `4066` data sheet.

Where is my error?

Comment: The diagram is incorrect. the CD4001 is a NOR gate, so both inputs have to be logic '0' for the output to be a logic '1'.

Comment: Seems like the cap and resistor across the switch is for debounce rather than for setting the startup state...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagram is incorrect. The CD4001 is a NOR gate, so both inputs have to be logic '0' for the output to be a logic '1', so your original 'expected' chart is correct. The symbol used in the schematic is wrong. It should have a dot on the output to indicate inversion.

The CD4001 NOR gate is used to make sure only one channel at a time is selected. At power reset, Channel 1 is selected.

This chart is correct, and it is what is taking place in the circuit.

1000 Channel 1

0100 Channel 2

0010 Channel 3

0001 Channel 4

[image]

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHH, fantastic! I missed that! THANKS!!!!!